# Scaffolding in Wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

is there any working, supported and maintained scaffolding solution for Wicket 1.5?
I know of

- Wicketopia at two different locations [sourceforge](http://wicketopia.sourceforge.net/) and [github](https://github.com/jwcarman/Wicketopia) but this is still targeted at wicket 1.4, brings it's own wicket and mails to the mailinglists didn't trigger any response in months.
- [Wicket Rad](http://sites.google.com/site/wicketrad/) but this hasn't been updated in 18 Months
- [Wicket CRUD](http://www.learntechnology.net/content/wicket/wicket_crud.jsp) which seems more like a tutorial or proof of concept than a working solution.

I can't belive, that there is no solution out there that allows to edit Domain Objects (selecting objects for OneToOne and add-remove-controls for lists would be a big plus). Writing editors isn't the most interesting part of developing a wicket application and getting them to look alike is tiring, so I'm looking for suggestions to automate this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [Apache Isis](http://incubator.apache.org/isis/viewer/wicket/index.html) for a domain driven approach. Perhaps you can find a CRUD framework at the Wicket WIKI page dedicated to [related projects](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/related-projects-and-tools.html). Maybe [databinder](http://databinder.net) is an option.

At my company we created our own CRUD framework. While it was not easy, it does give you an advantage and enables you to do things your own way.

Comment: Thanks. Databinder looks forked to death right now, so I'll go ahead and reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Has Apache Isis made any progress?

Comment: Yes, Apache Isis has made plenty of progress, and is being used to develop "real" applications.  Check out its website (http://isis.apache.org) for a quickstart archetype and screencasts.

Answer (score 0):

I spend few fours with wicket-webbeans ([WWB](http://code.google.com/p/wicket-web-beans/)). It isn't fully ported to wicket 1.5
(but some works have been done in 1.5 branch).

I think such project (automagicaly bean editor for Wicket 1.5) is very necessary

Comment: Wicketopia (16 May 2012 from sourceforge SVN) seems to have Wicket 1.5.6 support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple [CRUD web application](http://ujorm.org/sample/hotels.html) for hotel booking based on Wicket 6.0, Ujorm 1.40 and Spring 3.2 frameworks. Graphical interface is built on preview tables and form dialogs, see the next persistent class model:

[image]