# RAD tools for Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, rad

Was the Java Framework Wicket named as such given its similarities in speed and satisfaction to the 5-day version of the sport cricket which also uses wickets?

Probably.

Are you aware of any RAD tools that are **current** for use with wicket?
(i.e. scaffold generators, crud forms).

I've seen the outdated and seemingly forgotten WicketRad, Apache Isis, etc.

Comment: Not sure I understand your first question / paragraph. Are you suggesting that working with wicket is slow and long winded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked almost the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997688/scaffolding-in-wicket) about half a year ago. The results still seem valid to me:

- Wicket Rad but this hasn't been updated in 18 Months
- Wicket CRUD which seems more like a tutorial or proof of concept than a working solution.
- Wicketopia still on road to wicket 1.5

I haven't tried Apache Isis as it didn't come up in my research at that point. So I started a new pet-project developing CRUD components for wicket (Wicket-CRUDr) but since my time is very limited this is still ongoing.

To wrap this up: no, at this time there is no current, ready to use RAD tool for Wicket that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to know that [Apache Isis](http://isis.apache.org/) has recently massively updated their Wicket viewer. With recently added support for JDO, you should now have a total RAD solution with Wicket.

Comment: when I get a free moment, I will take a look.