# Displaying mysql crud table in wicket

Tags: hibernate, wicket, crud

I'm trying to find a way to create a table with CRUD functionality within a wicket page. I've never worked with anything like this. I was able to create a a Master Detail form using spring gui following this youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7pxkL2cZrw

but I can't figure out a way to use that same form data (from a table1.java file) it insert it into wicket with that CRUD functionality. Any suggestions welcome, and if you need more info, let me know.

EDIT:
code sample of table1 I want to show on wicket

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1", catalog = "mydatabase", schema = "")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Table1.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Table1 t"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Table1.findByNo", query = "SELECT t FROM Table1 t WHERE t.no = :no"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Table1.findByName", query = "SELECT t FROM Table1 t WHERE t.name = :name")})
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

@Transient
private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "no")
private Integer no;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Lob
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

public Table1() {
}

public Table1(Integer no) {
    this.no = no;
}

public Integer getNo() {
    return no;
}

public void setNo(Integer no) {
    Integer oldNo = this.no;
    this.no = no;
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange("no", oldNo, no);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    String oldName = this.name;
    this.name = name;
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    String oldAddress = this.address;
    this.address = address;
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange("address", oldAddress, address);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (no != null ? no.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Table1)) {
        return false;
    }
    Table1 other = (Table1) object;
    if ((this.no == null && other.no != null) || (this.no != null && !this.no.equals(other.no))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "javacrudapplication.Table1[ no=" + no + " ]";
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scaffolding in Wicket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997688/scaffolding-in-wicket)

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?